# Updating RaspberryPi Ubuntu Server 20.04 to 22.04 caused usercfg.txt to not be honored

Tags: ubuntu, config.txt, firmware

[I asked on askUbuntu a while back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462320/updating-raspberrypi-4b-from-ubuntu-server-20-04-to-22-04-caused-usercfg-txt-to) but didn't get much traction... should have known there was a stack for Raspi...

So I've been putting my HMDI output configuration in /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt

```
consoleblank=0
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=95
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
disable_overscan=1
```

After doing an in-place upgrade from focal to jammy it was only outputting 1920x1080

xrandr output showed:

```
$ xrandr -display :0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1280, current 1920 x 1280, maximum 1920 x 1280
default connected 1920x1280+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1280      0.00*
```

After a while I figured that I would try to put my my config into /boot/firmware/config.txt (which as I understand we're not supposed to do), but I'm troubleshooting.

And after a reboot we're all set, and the xrandr output shows:

```
$ xrandr -display :0
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 7680 x 7680
HDMI-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1428mm x 803mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   4096x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    59.94
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   720x480i      60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

Any ideas on what's going on?
Is this a bug?
Is /boot/firmware/config.txt the correct place to put these configurations now?

TYIA

Comment: Welcome.   Quick point: *"which as I understand we're not supposed to do"* -> It's the Pi SoC that uses these files at boot; the OS doesn't and in fact the first (small vfat) partition in which they are kept can be left unmounted -- the reason for mounting it is to provide access for modifying the configuration and doing updates.  Point being, I'd guess that ubuntu mounts it under `/boot/firmware` (whereas RPiOS mounts it on `/boot`), and conventionally `config.txt` **has always** been where the firm/hardware config options go...

Comment: ...How ubuntu deals with that I dunno, so it would be good if you could post a reference to where ever it is led you to believe anything else.  I'm not saying you are wrong, just that this is obviously a ubuntu specific issue, so it needs to be tackled in that context.

Comment: What model of Raspberry Pi is this?

Comment: @Dougie - It's both on 3b+ and 4b's

Comment: @goldilocks - The reason I'm thinking this is because if I do a do-release-upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 the new /boot/firmware/config.txt had the includes for usercfg.txt removed and the content from that file was added to config.txt with comments about being migrated during the release upgrade.

Also, from [here](https://www.theredreactor.com/2022/10/14/ubuntu/) the section titled "Configuring Power ON and OFF functions" mentions this, but doesn't reference a source for this information.

Comment: Okay, again that is in a Ubuntu context.  My point was that is *all* it has to do with (ubuntu) and not really the Pi, hence the change is probably about them moving toward a more "platform native" approach (the one used by most Pi users, since if the membership of this site is indicative of anything, most of them use Raspbian/RpiOS).  I have notice that some distros have tried to maintain generic ARM images that can be applied to a range of different little dev boards, and in order to do that they've needed to do various complexifying things with (eg.) the filesystem layout.

Comment: Anyway, the dependence on a file named `config.txt` on the first vfat partition is because the firmware/bootloader looks for and uses that.  Since some parts of that firmware are proprietary and only distributed as binaries, I would guess ubuntu can't change that, so in order to make it work with a more generic approach meant they used includes from there etc.  Why and who has said you're "not supposed to" use config.txt, though, is a little unclear because it doesn't really follow directly from that.

Comment: I was told to not use /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt

Comment: Originally the Ubuntu documentation said to use the usercft.txt and not use the config.txt but there was no notification of the change to only using config.txt and was hoping for someone with more experience to relay their thoughts.

[Ubutnu has a Pi specific ISO](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) and I've already asked the question in the askubuntu stack (linked in my OP) and figured that maybe this community would know more.